# Example of a Twitter Bootstrap typeahead in Grails?

Tags: jquery, grails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a text field which I’m trying to set up as a [Twitter Bootstrap typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) that calls a controller action to return a list of results for the user’s query so far, and I admit that I am slightly unsure of how to set this up. Can somebody give a simple example of how this sort of thing is done in Grails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the easiest usage of BootStrap Typeahead is to give it an array of values. So in the template create following Javascript, example for users:

```
var users = [
             <g:each in="users" var="u">
              '${ u.username } ( ${ u.first_name } ${ u.last_name } )',
             </g:each>
            ]

$( '#search_users' ).typeahead( { 'source': users } );
```

And in the HTML part:

```
<input type="text" id="search_users" />
```

Comment: This is really the only way since typeahead doesn't support remote queries.  If you want/need to do a remote query to get the list then you might have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/1848844

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what you're talking about.

First download the [Grails UI-plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ui) and it should be pretty simple. It was a while ago, but get back if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks, but Grails UI seems to not have been updated in a while (its original developer has moved on and whoever maintains it now isn’t aggressively keeping it up). Also I have to do this with Twitter Bootstrap’s typeahead.

Comment: Ok, shame! I accomplished to do it in more or less 15minutes - it was super simple and I used twitter's components, not really the auto-complete invoked from the twitter auto-complete.